# Spark lag with default value as another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, lag

Let's say we have

```
|bin | min |  end  | start | 
|1   | 5   | 10    | 
|2   | 12  | 24    | 
|3   | 28  | 36    | 
|4   | 40  | 50    | 
|5   | null| null  |
```

I would want to populate *start* as the previous column's *end* to make continuous bin values. For the missing I would like to fill in with the current *min* instead. For null row I consider treating it separately.

What lag gives us would be

```
df.withColumn("start", F.lag(col("end"), 1, ***default_value***).over(orderBy(col("bin"))
|bin | min |  end  | start | 
|1   | 5   | 10    | (5 wanted)
|2   | 12  | 24    | 10
|3   | 28  | 36    | 24
|4   | 40  | 50    | 36
|5   | null| null  | null
```

My questions :

1/ What do we put in ***default_value*** for lag to take another column of current row, in this case *min*

2/ Is there a way to treat null row at the same time without separating ? I intend to filter non-null , perform lag, then union back with the null rows. How will the answer differ if Null is the first(bin 1) or last (bin 5) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce` to get a column value for the first row in a group.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
df.withColumn("start", F.coalesce(F.lag(col("end"), 1).over(orderBy(col("bin")),col("min")))
```

`lag` currently doesn't support `ignorenulls` option, so you might have to separate out the `null` rows, compute the `start` column for non-null rows and `union` the data frames.